# Неявное преобразование char в int

Tags: c#, синтаксис, преобразование-типов

У Шилдта в книге написано: "В C# отсутствует автоматическое преобразование символьных значений в целочисленные и обратно". Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему такой код выполняется: `Console.WriteLine(3 + 'a')`, а такой не работает: `char x = 3 + 'a';`?

Comment: Вообще если вы поменяете тип `x` на `int` всё заработает.

Comment: *выполняется: Console.WriteLine(3 + 'a')* – обратите внимание, что он выводит

Comment: @YuriGo Нет, это не так. Вы можете выражение `3 + 'a'` присвоить целому типу.

Comment: @АндрейNOP То, что это выражение вообще выполняется, свидетельствует о том, что C# не сильно и строго типизирован, даже если результатом операции был не `int`, а `char`. И это как раз-таки и противоричит предложению Шилдта об автоматическом преобразовании.

Comment: *C# не сильно и строго типизирован* – это еще откуда такой вывод?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Да потому что такой код в действительно строго типизированном языке выполняться не должен. Также неявное преобразование целых в строки также противоречит идее строгой типизации: `string s = 3 + ""`

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, это небольшой сахарок, который заведомо не приводит к потере данных. Но от этого язык не становится слаботипизированным.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Неявные преобразования и операторы такого рода портят чистоту языка и его строгую типизацию. Если бы все преобразования надо было бы делать только явно, то язык избавился от всякого рода чёрной магии. К примеру, `IEnumerable<T>`, `List<T>` и т.д. — инвариантны в отличие от массивов. И это только плюс, вы не согласны? Видимо, в первой версии лажанули с этой "чёрной магией", а дальше уже надо был поддерживать обратную совместимость.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov `IEnumerable<T>` - инвариантен? Очень смешно...

Comment: @PavelMayorov А можно без едких фраз "смешно"? Да, с `IEnumerable<T>` ошибся. Но его не модифицируешь просто так, поэтому это может и имеет смысл. Но магии с примитивными типами многовато для строготипизированного языка в C#.

Comment: строго говоря, `char` это [ключевое слово](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/char), а примитивных символьных типов в C# вроде вообще нет :) только поэтому прямое присвоение вида `char a = (ushort)100;` не пройдёт.

Comment: @Alias Есть, а иначе зачем тогда [`Type.IsPrimitive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive(v=vs.110).aspx)? Кстати, `char` — ключевое слово, псевдноним `System.Char` — [источник](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/built-in-types-table).

Comment: *C# не сильно и строго типизирован* я не понял, какая связь между неявными преобразованиями и строгой типизацией? И можно как то определить меру строгой типизации, что  значит *не сильно*?

Comment: Нашёл у Шилдта в книге: "Результат выполнения всех арифметических операций будет иметь тип не ниже int."(преобразование типов в выражениях). Не состыковка только здесь: int = 'a';.

Comment: @tym32167 Дело в том, что существует разные критерии строгой типизации и отсутствие неявных преобразований один из них. В C# их наличие делает его менее **строгим** языком по сравнению с теми яыками, где они запрещены. Взаимосвязь увидеть очень просто — чем больше свободы в неявных преобразованиях типов, тем слабей типизация языка.   А меру строгой типизации можно пробовать определять по различным критериям.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov хм, я всегда считал, что строгая типизация - это когда конкретный экземпляр типа не может сменить свой тип в рантайме. То есть с моей точки зрения строгая типизация либо есть, либо нет - другого не дано. Однако, если говорить о причинах введения строгой типизации - строгого контроля над типами, то получается, что неявное приведение противоречит идее строгой типизации (и не помогает избегать ошибок работы с типами) и все языки, что поддерживают неявное приведение - тоже являются менее строгими. Кажется, я начал понимать вашу мысль, спасибо.

Comment: @tym32167 Когда тип задаётся в рантайме — это статическая типизация. Кстати, язык может быть динамически типизированным, но при этом строго типизированным (когда тип нельзя поменять в рантайме, он задаётся лишь раз, но на момент компиляции он неизвестен). Случай когда можно менять переменной тип в рантайме — это слабо типизированный язык с динамической типизацией.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поздравляю, вы нашли ошибку у Шилдта.

На самом деле в C# отсутствует автоматическое преобразование целочисленных значений в символьные. А вот в обратную сторону все прекрасно преобразуется:

```
int x = 'a';
Console.WriteLine(x); // 97
```

Comment: ну всё таки не всех целочисленных, `byte` или `short z = 'a';` не пройдёт, а только если по размеру влезет; просто символьный тип `char` в C#(.Net) по размеру 2х-байтовый беззнаковый `ushort`.